# How to refresh a view when resuming from Multitasking?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, multitasking

I have an app which is targeted to iOS 4 and above.I have a custom view, which is having
1.Scroll view
2.Custom drawing inside scroll view.

Now when my app is resuming from background,I want to refresh/reload this scroll view.
setNeedsDisplay is not working here as it usually meant for loading custom drawings and here I want to reload my scroll view contents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, `setNeedsDisplay` does not work for you in this case because you need to "reload" the data that the `UIScrollView` handles before doing the redraw.

If this is right, I would define a method in your controller that does the reloading part; then, I would call this method from `applicationDidEnterForeground` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`; the reload method will need to call `setNeedsDisplay`  after reloading the data.

I am sorry if this answer seems very generic to you. If you explain more or post some code, I can try and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redraw inside viewDidAppear?

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   [yourScrollView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Comment: This wont work as the view is already created. The application is resuming from background.

Comment: Then you could do the same thing in applicationDidEnterForeground instead

Answer (score 0):

setNeedDisplay calls the drawRect which is repainting operation. If you want to refresh the content only simply create one method in viewController and notify this method using performSelectorOnMainThread if you created new thread whenever thread complete (or you receive Data).